# MVC creates a new session after callback

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session-state

In our mvc project we have a user with session. User fills a form and after that we redirect to another website, than it's coming back to our callback url. At this point, system can't find the user and creates a new session which causes lots of troubles for us.

PS: Interesting thing, not all users are having this issue.

Comment: Sessions need cookies to be persistent, do all users allow cookies?

Comment: We are having this issue while working on project at localhost, too.

Comment: Without a clear set of code that reproduces the issue we can only make guesses which are likely not going to be of use.